# UICollectionReusableView can't ctrl drag UILabel IBAction

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a custom `UICollectionReusableView` that is the header view of a `UICollectionView`. There is a label on this header view, and I'd like to handle a tap event on the label.

For some reason, I'm unable to CTRL drag to create an IBAction to handle the click event. I've also tried adding a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to the label in the view's `initWithCoder()`. Although `initWithCoder()` gets called, the callback never gets called when the label is tapped.

Your help would be most appreciated! Thank you!

Here's the code inside the `UICollectionReusableView`:

```
-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];

    self.tapRecogniser = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(onLabelTap:)];
    [self.label1 addGestureRecognizer:self.tapRecogniser];

    return self;
}

-(void)onLabelTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tapGestureRecognizer;
{
    NSLog(@"Label tapped");
}
```

Comment: Can you provide some codes ? It can be useful understand where the problem is.

Comment: I'm trying to use storyboard to Ctrl+drag the label to the UICollectionReusableView to create an IBAction. I don't know what code I should show...

Answer (score 0):

The default value of [`userInteractionEnabled`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UILabel_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UILabel/userInteractionEnabled) property is `FALSE` for the class `UILabel`. Try to set it to `TRUE`.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I did set this flag in the storyboard already, but that didn't help.

Comment: Did you try to check if it is really set to TRUE when the xib is load?